# Crash trying to delete a second object

Tags: c++

This code use two classes, the first is the class lamp that switch its state between on, off and broken. the latter is the class switch that use a class lamp as one of its field.

the purpose of the code is to build a lamp and a switch. the switch change the state of the lamp, after a number of change of state the lamp broken itself.

the issue is that the programm chash itself on the second delete (delete switch1) can someone help me find why and how to correct it for the future.

```
#include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    

    //class lamp that switch its state between on, off and broken
    class Lamp{
    public:
        int lampState{};
        int breakPoint;
        int counter{};
    
        Lamp(const int& breakPoint){
            this->breakPoint = breakPoint;
        }
    
        string state(){
            switch(lampState){
            case 1:
                return "on";
                break;
            case 0:
                return "off";
                break;
            default:
                return "broken";
            }
    
        }
    
        void click(){
            if(counter == breakPoint){
                lampState = -1;
            }else if(lampState == 0){
                lampState = 1;
                counter++;
            }else if(lampState == 1){
                lampState = 0;
                conter++;
            }
        }
    
    };
    
    //class switch that push the switch to actually switch the state of the lamp
    class Switch{
    public:
        bool is_push{false};
        Lamp* lamp;
    
        Switch(Lamp* lamp){
            this->lamp = lamp;
        }
    
        void push(){
            lamp->click();
            if (is_push == false) {
                is_push = true;
            }else {
                is_push = false;
            }
        }
    
        ~Switch(){
            delete lamp;
        }
    
    };
    
    int main(){
        int numberClick{};
        cout << "insert  the number of click before the lamp break itself:";
        cin >> numberClick; cin.ignore();
        numberClick--;
    
        Lamp* lamp = new Lamp{numberClick};
    
        Switch* switch0 = new Switch{lamp};
        Switch* switch1 = new Switch(lamp
    
        bool ticket{true};
        int numSwitch{};
        while(ticket){
            cout << "choose what switch you want to use (insert 1 or 0 to use switch1 or switch0 use -1 to stop the programm): ";
            cin >> numSwitch; cin.ignore();
            if(numSwitch== -1 ){
                break;
            }else if (numSwitch == 0) {
                Switch0->push();
                cout << lamp->state() << endl;
            }else if (numSwitch== 1) {
                switch1->push
                cout << lamp->state() << endl;
            }
        }
    
        delete switch0;
        delete switch1;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: why do you think all those pointers (and related new and delete) are required?

Comment: Why do you need `new` `delete` for that example at all?

Comment: Step through the destructors and you'll see that you are double-deleting the lamp. You need to decide who is responsible for deleting the lamp. Right now, it seems that you are giving both switches that responsibility, which leads to confusion.

Comment: What is `conter`? I don't see its declaration anywhere.

Comment: because you deleted the lamp twice?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you delete the `lamp` in the `Switch` destructor. And since both switches are sharing the same lamp you delete the lamp twice. This crashes your program.

The simple answer (in this case) is not to use `new` and `delete`. There is no need for it in this code. Something like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


//class lamp that switch its state between on, off and broken
class Lamp{
public:
    int lampState{};
    int breakPoint;
    int counter{};

    Lamp(const int& breakPoint){
        this->breakPoint = breakPoint;
    }

    string state(){
        ...    
    }

    void click(){
        ...
    }

};

//class switch that push the switch to actually switch the state of the lamp
class Switch{
public:
    bool is_push{false};
    Lamp* lamp;

    Switch(Lamp* lamp){
        this->lamp = lamp;
    }

    void push(){
        lamp->click();
        if (is_push == false) {
            is_push = true;
        }else {
            is_push = false;
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    int numberClick{};
    cout << "insert  the number of click before the lamp break itself:";
    cin >> numberClick; cin.ignore();
    numberClick--;

    Lamp lamp{numberClick};

    Switch switch0{&lamp};
    Switch switch1{&lamp};

    bool ticket{true};
    int numSwitch{};
    while(ticket){
        cout << "choose what switch you want to use (insert 1 or 0 to use switch1 or switch0 use -1 to stop the programm): ";
        cin >> numSwitch; cin.ignore();
        if (numSwitch== -1 ){
            break;
        }else if (numSwitch == 0) {
            switch0.push();
            cout << lamp.state() << endl;
        }else if (numSwitch== 1) {
            switch1.push();
            cout << lamp.state() << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See how in `main` the lamp and switches **are not pointers**. It's a common beginner mistake to use pointers when they are not necessary.